# Parameters in Pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a task to send a list of cost-centers(varchar) to the query and the query should provide data based on each input.

I have no understanding of dynamic SQL.

So I have a list of cost centers like `88115100`, `88115200`, `88115300`......around 30.

```
declare @month integer

declare @month_2 integer
declare @startdate datetime
declare @enddate datetime
declare @costcenter varchar(20)

set @month_2= 3--/* t3.finncPriod=*/ '[%0]'
set @month=@month_2-1
set @costcenter='88115100'
set @startdate= '03/01/2019'--/*t0.docdate from oinm t0 where t0.docdate>=*/'[%1]'
set @enddate= '03/31/2019'--/*t0.docdate from oinm t0 where t0.docdate>=*/'[%2]'

select * from
(
    select
        t0.name+'-Budget' as 'toPivot',
        t4.AcctCode as 'GLAccount',
        t4.AcctName,
        isnull(t2.DebLTotal,0) as 'value' 
    from obgs as t0 
    inner join obgt as t1 on t0.AbsId = t1.Instance
    inner join bgt1 as t2
        on t2.Instance = t1.Instance
        and t2.AcctCode = t1.AcctCode
        and t2.Line_ID = @month
    inner join oact as t4 on t4.AcctCode = t2.AcctCode
    where t0.name = @costcenter 

    union all 

    select
        t0.name + '-Actual'as 't0Pivot',
        t4.AcctCode as 'GLAccount',
        t4.AcctName,
        isnull(sum(debit-credit),0) as 'value'
        from jdt1 as t3 
    left join oact t4 on t4.AcctCode = t3.Account
    left join obgs t0 on t0.Name = t3.ProfitCode
    left join obgt t1
        on t1.Instance = t0.AbsId
        and t4.AcctCode = t1.AcctCode
    left join bgt1 as t2
    on t1.Instance = t2.Instance
    and t2.AcctCode = t1.AcctCode
    and t2.line_ID = 2
    where
        t3.refdate between @startdate and @enddate
        and t4.ExportCode is not null
        and t0.name = @costcenter
    group by
        t0.name,
        t4.AcctCode,
        t4.AcctName

) as a
pivot 
(
    sum(a.value)
    for a.topivot in
    ([88115100-Budget], [88115100-Actual])
)
as pivottable
```

Comment: What is your question here. You start off by telling us what you have, then provide your SQL (attempt(s)?) but then? What is your goal here? What is your question? Can you provide sample data and expected results?

Comment: I want to convert this code into parameter based query where i can give user option to fill in cost centers

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to the site! You might like to have a look around the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and particularly [How to Ask...](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). I've tidied up your code here, but generally you'll be much more likely to get an answer if you provide nicely formatted code with a clear question in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so from what I can tell you probably want a [stored procedure](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_stored_procedures.asp), and you're suggesting that it could/should be dynamic SQL. Now, you *could* do that, but the only time you need dynamic SQL is when you have to rewrite keywords depending on variables. You *would* have to do that with your code above - specifically the following bit:

```
pivot 
(
    sum(a.value)
    for a.topivot in
    ([88115100-Budget], [88115100-Actual])
)
```

This is because `[88115100-Budget]` and `[88115100-Actual]` are keywords which depend on your variable (`@costcenter`). But there's no reason for them to be named like that in SQL! You're much better applying those names later, in whatever it is that you're sending this data to outside of SQL.

Instead, you probably want something like the following code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetBudgetForCostCenter
    @month integer = 2,
    @month_2 integer = 3,
    @startdate datetime = '03/01/2019',
    @enddate datetime = '03/31/2019',
    @costcenter varchar(20) = '88115100'
    --you probably don't actually want the default values in here, but I've left them for demonstration.
AS
BEGIN
    select * from
    (
        select
            'Budget' as 'toPivot',
            t4.AcctCode as 'GLAccount',
            t4.AcctName,
            isnull(t2.DebLTotal,0) as 'value' 
        from obgs as t0 
        inner join obgt as t1 on t0.AbsId = t1.Instance
        inner join bgt1 as t2
            on t2.Instance = t1.Instance
            and t2.AcctCode = t1.AcctCode
            and t2.Line_ID = @month
        inner join oact as t4 on t4.AcctCode = t2.AcctCode
        where t0.name = @costcenter 

        union all 

        select
            'Actual'as 't0Pivot',
            t4.AcctCode as 'GLAccount',
            t4.AcctName,
            isnull(sum(debit-credit),0) as 'value'
            from jdt1 as t3 
        left join oact t4 on t4.AcctCode = t3.Account
        left join obgs t0 on t0.Name = t3.ProfitCode
        left join obgt t1
            on t1.Instance = t0.AbsId
            and t4.AcctCode = t1.AcctCode
        left join bgt1 as t2
        on t1.Instance = t2.Instance
        and t2.AcctCode = t1.AcctCode
        and t2.line_ID = 2
        where
            t3.refdate between @startdate and @enddate
            and t4.ExportCode is not null
            and t0.name = @costcenter
        group by
            t0.name,
            t4.AcctCode,
            t4.AcctName

    ) as a
    pivot 
    (
        sum(a.value)
        for a.topivot in
        ([Budget], [Actual])
    )
    as pivottable
END
```

Note that I've changed your columns from `88115100-Budget` and `88115100-Actual` to just be `Budget` and `Actual`. This means that you can avoid using dynamic SQL which is something you should **always** aim to do.

This should now be able to be called via something like

```
exec GetBudgetForCostCenter @month = 2, @month_2 = 3, @startdate = '03/01/2019', @enddate = '03/31/2019', @costcenter = '88115100'
```

Disclaimer: I can't be bothered testing the syntax more than with the built-in syntax highlighting as it would require creating a new database and a lot of new objects, so sorry if there's any typos in there.